# Stuck on a simple if statement Python 3

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm very new to Python, and I've been wondering where to ask this question.
Well, I'm having a small difficulty with this small if statement.

I've broken it down, as the full if statement will be used in this small text RPG game.

```
health = 50

if(health > 100):
    health = 100
    print (health)

print (health)
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so the Health will never go above 100.
But typing

```
>>> health = 150
>>> print (health)
health = 150
```

And the IF statement hasn't been called.
I know this is probably a really easy fix for any experienced Python developer, but I simply cannot wrap my head around it.

Thanks,
Amos.

Comment: No, simply setting `health = 150` will not automatically call your `if` statement. You never ran that test again.

Comment: Looks like you want to use: `health = min(new_value, 100)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is not automatically run when you set `health` to 150. You'll need to *explicitly* execute it again to limit your health value.

You could make that a function:

```
def limit_health(health):
    if health < 0:
        health = 0
    if health > 100:
        health = 100
    return health

health = limit_health(150)
```

or you could just use `min()` to prevent health from going over 100:

```
health = min(health, 100)
```

If you are not averse to using classes, make `health` a property of the player:

```
class Player(object):
     MAX_HEALTH = 100 

     def __init__(self):
         # players start out with maximum health
         self.health = self.MAX_HEALTH

     # other things players track and can do

     @property
     def health(self):
         return self._health

     @health.setter
     def health(self, new_health):
         # limit health to MAX_HEALTH at most
         self._health = min(new_health, self.MAX_HEALTH)
```

then whenever you set `player.health` it'll be automatically limited for you.

Comment: I would be inclined to make the health limit an explicit class attribute, so  1. It's not just stuck in a method somewhere; and 2. you could e.g. have `class Dragon(Player): MAX_HEALTH = 150`. +1 otherwise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yeah; updated that to use a maximum health setting on the class, and initialising the health in `__init__` so it can be more easily inherited from.